# symfony 3.4 : forms : allow prototype for entity 's children

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections

My goal is to create chapter of a book and in each chapter, I can have as many chapters as I want as a subchapter. I have an entity which is a Chapter of a book
for each chapter, I can add a subchapter (which is in fact an other chapter ( but with id parent not null))

```
class Chapter
{       
    /**
     * One champ has One parent champ.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Chapter", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_parent", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public $parent; 
    
    /**
     * One champ has Many champs.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Chapter", mappedBy="parent",cascade={"persist"}))
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"ordre" = "ASC"})
     */
    public $children;
```

and I'd like to add/delete/modify with symfony form each chapter, so I have the following formtype

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    
    $builder->add('libelleLong', textType::class, ['label'=> 'titre']);

    
     $builder->add('children', CollectionType::class,[
         'entry_type' => ChapterType::class,
         'entry_options' => ['label' => false,'block_name' => 'childrenList'],
    
         'block_name' => 'childrenList',
         'label'=> false,
         'allow_add'=>true,
         'allow_delete'=> true,
         'prototype'=> true,
         'by_reference' => false,

         ]
     );             
}
```

but this line `'prototype'=> true` put everything down...

> [19-May-2020 20:57:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of
> 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in
> vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException.php
> on line 1

How can I allow prototype to the children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, the problem ultimately is recursion. since the child form will also have a `children` field, where all subforms will also have `children` fields ... ad infinitum. Hence it's running out of memory just to create this. (This problem only occured by adding `prototype` because it then has to render one future child, which also has prototype on, and has to do the same - please note, that the form component is not optimally equipped to handle recursion. maybe you can find a different way to technically and visually handle this, for example a list of (pos,string,depth) tuples, that optically improved by form rendering / js, with transformation etc.)

So you have to limit the depth this recursion can go. A generic approach (and tbh I'm not certain this will work) would be to add an option `max_depth`, which essentially tells the form builder if and how many more levels this can go.

For that, your form type class should include a method `configureOptions`:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired(['max_depth']);
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Chapter::class, // you probably have this line!
        'max_depth' => 3, // default value
    ]);
}
```

this will add the configuration option to your form type, now we have to use it in your `buildForm` method:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder->add('libelleLong', textType::class, ['label'=> 'titre']);

    // only add children sub form, if max_depth > 0, to stop infinite recursion
    if($options['max_depth'] > 0) { 
        $builder->add('children', CollectionType::class,[
             'entry_type' => ChapterType::class,
             'entry_options' => [
                   'label' => false,
                   'block_name' => 'childrenList',
                   // IMPORTANT!!! reduce max_depth by 1
                   'max_depth' => $options['max_depth'] - 1, 
             ],

             'block_name' => 'childrenList',
             'label'=> false,
             'allow_add' => true,
             'allow_delete'=> true,
             'prototype'=> true,
             'by_reference' => false,

         ]);
    } // end if for max_depth
}
```

I would advise to keep `max_depth` small, like ... 2 or 3.

An alternative would be, to create another form type called SubChapterType and maybe SubSubChapterType, that essentially are the same as ChapterType, except their `children`'s `entry_type` is the *next* form type, where the last form type has **no** `children` field.

Comment: the limit works fine !!!!
thx very much
1/ for the precision in your answer
2/ for the short time!!!